# Is it correct and natural to say "take off $25" meaning "make a discount of $25"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

Could you tell if it is correct and natural to say *take off $25* meaning *make a discount of $25*? For example:

> We ask $200 for that job, but I can **take off $25** and bring that to $175.

If it's not natural, would you please tell me what you would say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colloquially, "taking off $25" is perfectly fine to use!  In a more formal context, for example, you might hear "subtract $25 from".  Otherwise, all good.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, you would be more likely to say "I can knock off $25" or more formally "I can give you a $25 discount". Giving sounds much more positive than taking off. And no businessperson would *ever* say "subtract $25 from".